# Terminal Crashes on start

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I changed something in ~/.bashrc and after I sourced it,
my Terminal hasn't started anymore.

It just starts without any Text and crashes after a few seconds, I tried to restore the old .bashrc-file, but it didn't change anything.

There isn't a color scheme anymore either, I have absolutly no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing and reinstalling the Pantheon Terminal through the App Center.

If you run into any other issue that might require access to a working terminal you can install the Gnome Terminal through the App Center and use that to fix whatever might need fixing.

Refer to these [instructions](https://adam.merrifield.ca/2015/11/23/4-steps-to-replace-the-terminal-in-elementary-os-freya/) if you want to set Gnome Terminal as your permanent replacement.